# How to solve the below design problem in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base  interface

```
export interface Notification {
  context: EventContext;
  notifications: NotificationResult;
}
```

and there are other derived interfaces like below

```
export type AddRowNotification = Notification & {
'experimentId': string;
'rows': Array<string>;
'tableId': string;
};
```

From the API response i get response based on the Base interface **Notification** covering up all the derived types. Now the challenge here is to retrieve each of the required type by typecasting one by one, with an if or switch condition to check if it is the required derived type. The switch cases would increase if the no of derived types increases.

Is there any better approach to solve the above issue ?

Comment: I think your question may benefit from further clarification - what is the "required type", typecasting what, etc ... maybe add the code with your if-based solution that might get improved?

Comment: Why not use generics?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is not a more elegant solution than performing N conditional checks if you need to differentiate between N types. Remember that types are compiled away at run-time, so if you want to take a different action based on the type (e.g. expect `experimentId` to be present if the type is `AddRowNotification` but not be present if the type is `SomeOtherNotification`), then you need to do this in a way that JavaScript would also understand, i.e. with some conditional check on the actual content of the underlying object

The TypeScript way of achieving this while also providing type safety/understanding of the type is with a Type Guard (see [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

Unfortunately this does not remove the need for having one function/check per type, but it does mean you do not need to manually cast types to get type safety downstream.

An example with your use case:

`types.ts`

```
export interface Notification {
  context: EventContext;
  notifications: NotificationResult;
}

export interface AddRowNotification extends Notification {
  experimentId: string;
  rows: Array<string>;
  tableId: string;
}

export interface SomeOtherNotification extends Notification {
  someOtherKey: string;
}

export type NotificationTypes =
  | AddRowNotification
  | SomeOtherNotification
```

`type-guards.ts`

```
function isAddRowNotification(notification: NotificationTypes): notification is AddRowNotification {
  return 'tableId' in notification; // Note: This can be any property on AddRowNotification as long as it does not appear on any other type
}

function isSomeOtherNotification(notification: NotificationTypes): notification is SomeOtherNotification {
  return 'someOtherKey' in notification;
}
```

`some-file.ts`

```
function handleNotification(notification: NotificationTypes): void {
  if (isAddRowNotification(notification)) {
    // notification is of type AddRowNotification
    notification.context       // valid
    notification.experimentId  // valid
    notification.someOtherKey  // error: Property 'someOtherKey' does not exist on type 'AddRowNotification'.(2339)
  }
  else if (isSomeOtherNotification(notification)) {
    // notification is of type AddRowNotification
    notification.context       // valid
    notification.experimentId  // error: Property 'experimentId' does not exist on type 'SomeOtherNotification'.(2339)
    notification.someOtherKey  // valid
  }
  else {
    // notification is of type never as NotificationTypes only supports 2 possible notification types and both are not true
    notification.context       // error: Property 'context' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)
    notification.experimentId  // error: Property 'experimentId' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)
    notification.someOtherKey  // error: Property 'someOtherKey' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)
  }
}
```